# Polar transformation of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` 2048 by 2048 with `index` and `columns` representing y and x coordinates respectively.

I want to make an axis transformation and get to polar coordinates, making a new `pandas.DataFrame` with `index` and `columns` representing radius and polar angle.
The only way I can think of is access the dataframe values one by one, calculating radius and angle and then setting the according value in the new dataframe, but it is extremely slow, since element-wise operations are not that fast in pandas. It's still slow even if I perform the operation row-by-row.

Is there a better way to do that without writing my own CPython extension in C?

Comment: Please can you show small input/output example DataFrames?

Comment: @ajcr Sorry, it's tricky with the examples. I only have the examples of input, and they are way too large. But in the input indexes and columns are arithmetic progressions of integers. In the output it's almost the same: radius is arithmetic progression of integers, angle is `np.arange` with the chosen step.

Comment: Can you make a 10x10 example?  That could help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be problematic if your dataframe is built as I understand it (though I think I am wrong).  To build an example:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

index = np.arange(1,2049,dtype=float)
cols  = np.arange(2050,4098,dtype=float)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=cols)

# now calculate angle and radius, then set in new dataframe
phi = np.arctan(df.columns/df.index)
r   = np.power( np.power(df.index,2) + np.power(df.columns,2), 0.5 )

df_polar = pd.DataFrame(index=r, columns=phi)
```

While this agrees with what you stated, I think I have missed something here.  If this is not right, can you clarify?

Comment: This is correct. The only thing you got wrong is `cols  = np.arange(1,2049,dtype=float)`. So is what I'm asking impossible?

Comment: I just made up the "index" and "cols" values so they can be whatever you want them to be (I set cols = np.arange(2050,4098) just to make that different from index).  I am still unsure of what you are doing here.  If you set cols = np.arange(1,2049,dtype=float) then cols==index and all of your phi and r values will be the same and there is little utility in writing code for that.  I assumed you have differing x/y pairs, hence index<>cols, correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot that `np.arctan(df.columns/df.index)` will produce an array of shape same as `df.index` or `df.columns`. That's not right for me. I need all values from someting like `np.arctan((i / j for i in df.columns for j in df.index))`, and same for `r   = [np.power(np.power(i,2) + np.power(j,2), 0.5 ) for i in df.columns for j in df.index]`

Comment: You realize that for a 2048x2048 dataframe this will yield a dataframe with 17,592,186,044,416 values right?  Perhaps a small example (maybe 10x10) is necessary at this point to ensure I understand what you are doing.